# insert dynamic data from datalist into database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using visual studio and c# to create a staff rota system where staff member's names from the "Staff" table are displayed in a datalist. As well as this, I have created 2 dropdown lists in asp, separate from the "Staff" table, although they appear in the item template tag to enable them to be dynamically created next to the staff names. The user can then select the staff's shift start and end times from the dropdowns.

I decided to use a datalist and dynamic dropdowns as the Staff table will frequently be updated as new staff may start or leave, therefore rota's in the future may contain different numbers of staff.

```
    <table class="style57" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="style70" width="100%">
                        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="StaffHours" 
                            ShowFooter="False" Width="668px" Height="16px" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1"">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                            <td class="style76" width="0%">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblStaffID" runat="server" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" Visible=false Text='<%# Eval("StaffID") %>'/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style73" width="20%">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'/>
                                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%"> 
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStartShift" runat="Server">
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="Start Time" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="06:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="07:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="08:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="09:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="10:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="11:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="12:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="13:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="14:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="15:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="16:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="17:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="18:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="19:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="20:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="21:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="22:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="23:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="00:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="01:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="02:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="03:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="04:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="05:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td width="10%"> 
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddEndShift" runat="Server">
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="End Time" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="06:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="07:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="08:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="09:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="10:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="11:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="12:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="13:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="14:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="15:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="16:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="17:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="18:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="19:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="20:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="21:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="22:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="23:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="00:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="01:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="02:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="03:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="04:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem  Value="05:00"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                         </table>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="StaffHours" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [StaffID], [FirstName], [LastName] FROM [Staff]">
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

As these dropdowns are dynamically created in the datalist, I cannot figure out how to insert their values for each staff member into the "Rota" table as they are not identified therefore I cannot enter them into a parameter for a stored procedure.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Man, you have to share code here... I don't have many  herbs to imagine what do you did... )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `DataKeyField` of the `DataList` to `StaffID`:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="StaffHours" 
DataKeyField = "StaffID" ShowFooter="False" Width="668px" 
Height="16px" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1"">
```

This will allow you to retrieve the StaffID when processing your data on postback:

```
for(int index = 0;index < DataList1.Items.Count;index++)
{
    int staffID = (int) DataList1.DataKeys[index];
    DropDownList ddStartShift = (DropDownList) DataList1.Items[index].FindControl("ddStartShift");
    // etc.

}
```

For more on the DataKeys property:  [BaseDataList DataKeys Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.datakeys.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have inserted your suggestion above, although the staffID and dropdown lists are not recognized when I try to create a parameter for them to be inserted into my database.

Comment: When you say "create a parameter for them", do you mean using the `SqlDataSource`?  That's because they're embedded in the DataList: they're in a different naming container from the `SqlDataSource`, one defined by the `DataListItem`s of the `DataList`.  You'll have to do it in code, by looping through the DataListItems and retrieving the values the way I showed in my example.